# Adding Composer Package to Laravel Providers array

Tags: php, laravel, woocommerce, composer-php

I'd like to understand how the path for various composer packages is constructed in the providers array of the app.php in Laravel. Some documentation include the line you need to copy/paste but I want to find out how to do this myself.

**Example**

The JWTAuth package has the following line:

```
Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider::class
```

However, the path to this class is **tymon\jwt-auth\src\JWTAuthServiceProvider.php**

I want to know how this path is constructed.

Next I want to know how I can include the Woothemes/Woocommerce api package in the providers array. How do I construct this path?

The package can be found at **https://packagist.org/packages/woothemes/woocommerce-api**

I have done some research and found that this package is not specifically written for Laravel. The bootstrap file **woocommerce-api.php** just contains the require_once() functions for the classes.

Would it be acceptable to do,

```
require_once base_path('vendor/woothemes/woocommerce-api/woocommerce-api.php');
```

in my controller file?

Answer (score 1):

This

```
Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider
```

is not a filesystem path, it's the class' namespace.

As the package you linked to isn't written for laravel, there is no ServiceProvider for it yet, but [you are free to create one](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/packages).

However, you can use every external package without a ServiceProvider in laravel. You wouldn't `require_once` anything, but you would

```
use FullNamespace\Name\To\Class
```

at the top of your file, e.g. have a look at one of your controllers, it's the same as here:

```
<?php namespace App\CreateTables;

use Config;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use MeineBuyBox\UserDatabase;
use Schema;
```

That way, the class you intend to use will be loaded in the file you need it to be in and you can use it now.

Comment: Including the "use" statement for the class I required worked, but I added a "libraries folder" in my app directory and included this folder in the composer.json. Did a composer dump-autoload and the error is gone.

Comment: What did you include in the `libraries folder`? I hope it wasn't the package, because when you do `composer update` this package will be ignored.